# How to implement a group by query having min and max in R using dplyr or other package?

Tags: r, performance, group-by, aggregate-functions

How to implement this query in R using dplyr package?

```
df2 = sqldf('select A, B, min(C), count(distinct(d))
               from df1
              where A = 1
                and B = "xyz"
              group by A, B')
```

I am using ***sqldf*** at the moment by for performance improvement, I want to use ***dplyr*** or any other suitable package.

Comment: Have a look at https://db.rstudio.com/dplyr/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work?

```
df2=filter(df1,A==1 & B == "xyz")%>% group_by(A,B)%>%
  summarise(min_C=min(C), min_d=max(d), med_E=median(E))
```

Answer (score 0):

for increase performance of this query

```
df2 = sqldf('select A, B, min(C), max(d), median(E)
           from df1
          where A = 1
            and B = "xyz"
          group by A, B')
```

be sure  you  have index  on  table df1  column A, B

```
create index my_idx ON df1 (A, B)
```

or

```
create index my_idx ON df1 (A, B, C, D,E)
```

in the second way  .. all the values are retrived  directly form the index  reducing the access to data table

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for something using R commands and packages rather than standard SQL practices such as indexing. Can we write and equivalent query using say dplyr or other packages?

Comment: as you use SQL for a query you can use command for create  index ..  .. so you can simply use `sqldf(' create index my_idx ON df1 (A, B, C, D,E)')` . .. remember that the performance for data access are based on mysql db engine  ..and change the question  .. after  an answer is not fair  ..

Comment: Thanks again but it is fair because in my original question itself I had mentioned that I specifically wanted using dplyr or any other R package because I was specifically looking for a R specific answer not a general SQL.answer. Hence I had to change to avoid non R answers.